# find() not working for a character in a string (C++)

Tags: c++

So i am using find in the algorithm library of C++ to check if each character in a string is present in a string vector, but the problem i am facing with the find function is that this does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string s = "hello";
    vector<string> v = {"h", "e", "l", "o"};
    if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), s[0]) != v.end()) {
        cout << "found";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But replacing `s[0]` with a string literal like this works:

```
if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), "h") != v.end()) {
        cout << "found";
    }
```

Checking online I found that [] operator returns a reference to a char, so i tried de-referencing it as `*s[0]` which gave the error:

> invalid type argument of unary '*'

Comment: "this does not work". What is the error message when the first one doesn't work? Instead of trying random things, read the error message.

Comment: @NoName, that did not work

Comment: @JohnFilleau `error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' and 'const char')
  270 |         { return *__it == _M_value; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s[0]` is a character, so it cannot directly compared to strings.

You can make it work by first constructing a string from a character.

```cpp
if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), string(1, s[0])) != v.end()) {
    cout << "found";
}
```

Another option is using a substring as the query.

```cpp
if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), s.substr(0, 1)) != v.end()) {
    cout << "found";
}
```